# WebBrowser и нестандартная письменность

Tags: c#, wpf, шрифты, unicode

Довольно специфичная проблема. Есть приложение WPF, которое тянет компонент форм WebBrowser. Через него открывает веб-страницу, но веб-страница писана бирманской письменностью. У неё с юникодом [были жуткие траблы аж до 2005 года](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burmese_script), сайты отдавали текст картинками.

При открытии страницы в браузере, честно говоря, у меня и сейчас на долю секунды появляются квадратики, которые затем превращаются в нормальное письмо. То ли браузер тормозит от этих знаков, то ли сервер выдаёт по-прежнему их как-то нестандартно.

Как бы там ни было, древний необновляемый компонент WebBrowser отображает письмо квадратиками. Что в этом случае делать?

Куда копать? Каким-то образом подключать отсутствующие шрифты? Или проблема в ином?
Если шрифт, то как это сделать? Текст может быть не только на бирманском, но и смесь.

```
(webBrowser.Child as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser).Navigate("https://my.wikipedia.org");
```

Comment: Для чего используется вебброузер ? не проще получить код гет-запросом, обработать и отобразить результат скажем в ричтекстбокс !?

Comment: @DigitalCore нет, увы, но прога должна работать напрямую с html, без парсинга.

Comment: используйте Chromium в таком случае, с обработкой JS и прочих.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать более современный CefSharp.WPF Nuget-пакет. Там будет браузерный контрол, основанный на Chromium.